# Can I change current DateTime WITHOUT effecting other programs?

Tags: c#, datetime

I need to simulate an App that references DateTime.utcNow.

I would like to change the time that is returned, but do not want to mess up my PC and taskschedulers etc.

Is it possible to change what is returned from DateTime.Now and DatetIme.utcNow, purely within contexts of the program itself?

Comment: I do not believe that is possible. This is one of the use cases for [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). All your time-related calls would go through a custom interface whose implementation you can then mock and/or customize as needed.

Comment: What's preventing you from using a different computer or even a VM?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't change what the property returns but you don't *have* to call the property - you could call a function that returns the time you need. You could pass a reference to the function as a Func<DateTime> to whoever needs it, store it as a Funct<DateTime> typed field etc.

Comment: If you want to process events, look up [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985(v=vs.103).aspx). Reactive Extensions have the notion of [Virtual Time](http://haacked.com/archive/2014/03/10/master-time-with-reactive-extensions/) to allow you to manipulate time, particularly in testing scenarios. A [VirtualTimeScheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229167(v=vs.103).aspx) controls not only the reported time but how fast time runs, can rerun previous periods etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this without implementing dependency injection everywhere is to replace all calls to `DateTime.UtcNow` with `SystemTime.UtcNow()` and add the following class.

```
public static class SystemTime
{       
    public static Func<DateTime> UtcNow = () => DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

and then in your simulation code, you can replace the returned code with

```
SystemTime.UtcNow = () => new DateTime(2000,1,1);
```

Don't forget you might need to do the same for `DateTime.Now`, `DateTime.Today`, etc. Also, you can add a function so that you can return to the 'normal' behaviour with `SystemTime.Reset()`.

```
public static class SystemTime
{       
    public static Func<DateTime> UtcNow = () => DateTime.UtcNow;
    public static Func<DateTime> Now = () => DateTime.Now;
    public static Func<DateTime> Today = () => DateTime.Today;

    public static void Reset()
    {
        UtcNow = () => DateTime.UtcNow;
        Now = () => DateTime.Now;
        Today = () => DateTime.Today;            
    }
}
```

Comment: DI everywhere isn't bad: instead of calling SystemTime.UtcNow, classes accept a `Func<DateTime>()` parameter/property. You avoid spreading static calls throughout the code